# Customize tree icon on ag grid

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I want to add icon before the tree view in ag grid in first column before the collapse and expand arrow and also the leaf level.. how can i write custom render for this thing.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Try to add some UI and codes or fiddle explaining your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can add icon or button in first column in tree view as below:-

```
 autoGroupColumnDef: {
                headerName: 'OrgHierarchy',
                field: 'OrgHierarchy'
            //user valueGetter and valueSetter
                 valueGetter: (params) => {

                },
                valueSetter: (params) => {
                    return true;
                },
                cellRendererParams: {
                    suppressCount: true,
                    innerRenderer: 'orgHierarchyRenderer',  //<=====add it as
                },

}

components: {
  orgHierarchyRenderer: this.OrgHierarchyRenderer(),
}


 OrgHierarchyRenderer() {
        function orgHierarchyRenderer() {}
        orgHierarchyRenderer.prototype.init = function (params) {
            this.eGui = document.createElement('div');
            this.eGui.innerHTML = params.value;

            // add buttons or any icon as below and style to position
            this.btnEle = document.createElement('button');
            this.btnEle.className = 'btnDivDetails';
            this.btnEle.innerHTML = "Details <i class='kr-right_arrow'></i>";
            this.btnEle.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
                
                }
            
            });
            this.eGui.appendChild(this.btnEle);
        };

        orgHierarchyRenderer.prototype.getGui = function () {
            return this.eGui;
        };
        orgHierarchyRenderer.prototype.getValue = () => {
            return this.eGui;
        };
        orgHierarchyRenderer.prototype.destroy = function () {};
        orgHierarchyRenderer.prototype.isPopup = function () {
            return false;
        };
        return orgHierarchyRenderer;
    }
}
```

Comment: Any idea how can I pass data to the renderer?   
I can get row data using `params.data` in some cases but in other cases, it just doesn't have anything other than `params.value` which I can't use to distinguish what type of cell it is.

Comment: For grouped nodes, params.data may not be coming. Can you please ask a new question and describe what is the issue, so that it should be more clear.

Comment: I managed to solve my issue for now but I will add a new Question sometime soon because my use case was rather easier to fix.
Basically, I needed to fetch the icon from row data (`params.data`) but as we've established that in case of Tree Grid, the `params.data` doesn't always have a value so I was unable to fetch the icon but then I used the `params.node.level` to show different icons for my 4 level data. As you can imagine, this is a simple scenario which won't help much in case of complex & deeply dependent requirements.

Comment: Soon after adding the above comment, I had another thought that maybe my rowData wasn't configured properly. To my surprise, that was the case. So, you see 
`const rowData = [
    { orgHierarchy: ['Erica'], jobTitle: "CEO", employmentType: "Permanent" },
    { orgHierarchy: ['Erica', 'Malcolm'], jobTitle: "VP", employmentType: "Permanent" }
]`
is different than just 
`const rowData = [
     { orgHierarchy: ['Erica', 'Malcolm'], jobTitle: "VP", employmentType: "Permanent" }
]`

Answer (score 0):

Adding Icons before the Expanding/Collapse arrow is not possible out of the box using Cell Renderer Components, however you can leverage CSS to do this.

For example, targeting the grouping nodes and then adding an icon (in this case, Font Awesome icon):

```
    .ag-theme-alpine span.ag-row-group::before {
      font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
      font-weight: bold;
      content: '\f00d';
      color: red;
    }
```

Please see the following example to see how: https://plnkr.co/edit/Dn5nIqzyaeOFld9q